# Call constructor with and without parameter with PowerMockito

Tags: java, mocking, powermockito

I'm struggling try to understand how PowerMockito works.

What I'm trying to test, is a method that call two method of the same class, and also a method on a joda `DateTime` class, who, as you know, is a final class, so it's impossible to mock with Mockito.
That's why I using (after hours of investigation) Powermockito.

I'm using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest` with the two classes (the one being tested and the `joda.time.DateTime`), and my `setUp()` looks similar to this

```
target = new ClassToBeTested();
DateTime TODAY = new  DateTime(2016, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0);
PowerMockito.whenNew(DateTime.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(TODAY);
```

This four lines of code represent hours of investigation, test and errors, but they worked: inside the method of 'target' that I need to test, when I create a `DateTime` object with no arguments, so I could use it to know the current day, it return the `TODAY` object.
The problem is that, inside that method, I need also to create another couple of `DateTime` Objects, and initialized them with difference  dates (the logic of the method involves compare this two dates with the current day and take actions), so, I thought that the solution could be

```
DateTime TODAY = new  DateTime(2017, 8, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime createdOn = new DateTime(2016, 7, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime recordedOn = new DateTime(2016, 7, 7, 12, 20, 0, 0);
PowerMockito.whenNew(DateTime.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(TODAY);
PowerMockito.whenNew(DateTime.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(createdOn, recordedOn);
```

But when I tried, I received `createdOn` instead of `TODAY` in the `DateTime` constructor with no parameters, and then the correct `createdOn` and `recordedOn`. It's like if the line `withAnyArguments` invalidate the `withNoArguments`

To show you more clearly what I tried to do, this is how looks like the method to be tested (only the important part)

```
DateTime today = new DateTime(); //To know current day, I was hoping that the withNoArgument take care of this returning TODAY. But it really received createdOn        
DateTime createdOnDay = new DateTime(this.getDateCreated()); it received , createdOnd       
DateTime recordedOnDay = new DateTime(this.getDateRecorded());
// It received recordedOn.
```

Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: That's probably because any argument is also valid for no argument (I assume nothing is anything). You could probably get around using `withArgument(Date.class)` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but sadly that doesn't work. withArgument does't receive an "object type" or something, but an specific value.

Comment: Have you added **ClassToBeTested** to '@PrepareForTest'. I mean that class which uses 'DateTime' constructor should also be added to annotation.

Comment: @ArthurZagretdinov yes, I did

Answer (score 0):

Side remark: it's highly discouraged to use PowerMockito "mockNew", you should always when possible refactor the code under test to allow testing.

---

With this:

**`Foo`:**

```
package so36119627;

public class Foo {

    private final String bar;

    public Foo(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Foo() {
        this("hello");
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

**`Bar`:**

```
package so36119627;

public class Bar {
    public String bar() {
        return new Foo().getBar() + " / " + new Foo("world").getBar();
    }
}
```

the following test runs fine and do what you want:

```
package so36119627;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Matchers;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class, Bar.class})
public class BarTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("hello / world", new Bar().bar());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        // do not inline foo1 and foo2, because of powermock
        final Foo foo1 = new Foo("with arg");
        final Foo foo2 = new Foo("no arg");
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withArguments(Matchers.anyString()).thenReturn(foo1);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(foo2);

        assertEquals("no arg / with arg", new Bar().bar());
    }
}
```